# How do I find consecutive strings in my array that match a regex?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to find consecutive tokens in my array of strings that match a regular expression.  So if my regex is

```
/\p{L}/
```

and my array is

```
 ["2917", "m", "neatty", "fff", "46", "u", "28", "56"]
```

I would want the result to be

```
["m", "neatty", "fff"]
```

However, my attempt to do this has failed (notice the "neatty" token is repeated) ...

```
2.4.0 :020 > arr = ["2917", "m", "neatty", "fff", "46", "u", "28", "56"]
 => ["2917", "m", "neatty", "fff", "46", "u", "28", "56"]
2.4.0 :021 > arr.each_cons(2).select{|pair| pair.all?{|elem| elem =~ /\p{L}/ }}.flatten
 => ["m", "neatty", "neatty", "fff"]
```

How do I find consecutive tokens in an array that match a pattern that also don't repeat?

Comment: What is the expected result for `["1", "m", "m", "2", "m"]` input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `r` is your regex then use `chunk_while`

```
arr.chunk_while { |a,b| a[r] && b[r] }.select { |arr| arr.size > 1 }     
 #=> [["m", "neatty", "fff"]]
```

Comment: I assume "r" is my regex?  Also this will return an array of arrays so to get to the output I want, can I just apply flatten?

Comment: yes `r` is your regex (sorry I will update my answer). I left the answer as a 2-D array in case you have more than 1 set of consecutive matches, which could happen. But yeah, flatten it if you like.

Comment: Please note, that unless the question I posted in comments (What is the expected result for `["1", "m", "m", "2", "m"]` input? ) is answered by OP, this answer correctness is in undetermined state :).

Comment: @mudasobwa: How do you see the ambiguity of `["1", "m", "m", "2", "m"]`? Wouldn't the answer be `[["m", "m"]]`?

Comment: @dawg I read the OP and it clearly stated: “that also don't repeat” for the returned strings.

Comment: I *think* he meant the overlapping `["neatty", "neatty"]` he was getting from using `each_cons(2)` -- a created duplicate because of the method. I could be wrong tho. Good question since his method would result in `["m","m"]` from your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `slice_when` to find borders of the sub array that bound the condition:

```
> arr.slice_when {|x,y| !x[reg] || !y[reg] }.select {|e| e.length>1}
=> [["m", "neatty", "fff"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["2917", "m", "neatty", "fff", "46", "u", "28", "56", "hi", "%ya!"]
r = /\p{L}/

arr.each_with_object([[]]) { |s,a| s.match?(r) ? (a.last << s) : a << [] }.
    reject { |a| a.size < 2 }
  #=> [["m", "neatty", "fff"], ["hi", "%ya!"]]
```